# Python: Abstract method called recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a main class called Message and a subclass called DDMessage. When I  create an object DDMessage with:

```
m = DDMessages(row["language"])
```

I've got this error:

[image]

The code of each class are ...

**Message**

```
import abc


class Message(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

def __init__(self, language):
    self.set_message(language)

@abc.abstractmethod
def set_message(self, language):
    raise NotImplementedError("Message", "set_message", None,
                      "El usuario no ha implementado este método")

def get_message(self):
    return self.message

@abc.abstractmethod
def prepare_message(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("Message", "prepare_message", None,
                      "El usuario no ha implementado este método")
```

**DDMessage**

```
from messages.message import Message
from constants import MESSAGES
from constants import LANGUAGE


class DDMessages(Message):


    def __init__(self, language):
        super().__init__(language)

    def set_message(self, language):
        if language == LANGUAGE.SPANISH:
            self.set_message(MESSAGES.DD_ESP_MESSAGE)
        else:
            self.set_message(MESSAGES.DD_ENG_MESSAGE)

    def prepare_message(self):
        pass
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm working with python 3.

Comment: Your `set_message` method in `DDMessages` has a simple conditional branch, and you call itself recursively in each branch.

Comment: What is the purpose of the recursive call `self.set_message()`? I think this doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: maybe the OP means to do `self.message = var`?  as a minor point, it might be worth pointing to the `gettext` package which helps with internationalisation

Comment: If you are using python3, the recommended way to make abstract class is to inherit from `abc.ABC`. So `class Message(abc.ABC):` instead of `class Message(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):`

Comment: code for NotImplementedError?

Comment: Ooooh!!!! I'm blind!!! I can't see that I was calling again the function instead to assign the value to self.message!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @JoséCarlos Sam Mason makes a good point. You should look for other packages to do your internationalization such as `gettext`.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice and Sam Mason for the recommendation!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `set_message()` calls itself. This is what recursion means. I don't think recursion is appropriate here. Instead, you should set the message field of the instance:

```
def set_message(self, language):
    if language == LANGUAGE.SPANISH:
        self.message = MESSAGES.DD_ESP_MESSAGE
    else:
        self.message = MESSAGES.DD_ENG_MESSAGE
```

This is just a guess, though. If this isn't what you want, you need to step away from your computer and figure out what you want to do. If you need further help, don't hesitate to ask a new question describing in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! How I said in other message, I didn't see that I was calling the function again instead to assign the value to self.message!!!